# extract data from a cut plane

Tags: python, vtk

I wrote the following code (simplified for better reading) to read a structured grid and draw a cut plane through my volume. Everything is OK concerning the visualization: I get a nice contour plot with the cut plane passing through it. However, I failed to extract the data showed in the cut plane. Is there a way to extract the coordinates and data ("Intensity" - see below) associated with my cut plane ?

```
self._reader = vtk.vtkXMLStructuredGridReader()
self._reader.SetFileName(filename)
self._reader.Update()

self._reader.GetOutput().GetPointData().SetActiveScalars("Intensity")

self._isoContour = vtk.vtkContourFilter()
self._isoContour.SetInputConnection(self._reader.GetOutputPort())
self._isoContour.SetValue(0,100)

self.mapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
self.mapper.SetInputConnection(self._reader.GetOutputPort())
self.mapper.ScalarVisibilityOn()
self.mapper.Update()

self._surface = vtk.vtkActor()
self._surface.SetMapper(self.mapper)
self._surface.GetProperty().SetRepresentationToWireframe()

plane = vtk.vtkPlane()
plane.SetOrigin(self._reader.GetOutput().GetCenter())
plane.SetNormal(0, 0, 1)

planeCut = vtk.vtkCutter()
planeCut.SetInput(self._reader.GetOutput())
planeCut.SetCutFunction(plane)

cutMapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
cutMapper.SetInputConnection(planeCut.GetOutputPort())
cutMapper.SetLookupTable(table)
cutMapper.SetScalarRange(0,100)

cutActor = vtk.vtkActor()
cutActor.SetMapper(cutMapper)

self._renderer.AddActor(self._surface) 
self._renderer.AddActor(cutActor)

self._iren.Render()
```

thanks a lot for your help

Eric

Answer (score 1):

this is what I would do, to write out the data:

```
self._reader.GetOutput().GetPointData().SetActiveScalars("Intensity")

planeCut = vtk.vtkCutter()
planeCut.SetInput(self._reader.GetOutput())
planeCut.SetCutFunction(plane)

planeCut.Update()

#DataSet of your cut:
planeCutPolyData=planeCut.GetOutput()

#Let write all the slice data:
w=vtk.vtkPolyDataWriter()
w.SetFileName('anyfilename.vtp')
w.SetInputConnection(placeCut.GetOutputPort())
w.Write()
```

vtk users is a good place to look for examples. Here is a question already ansered on extracting coordinates from a polyData:
http://vtk.1045678.n5.nabble.com/Polydata-get-point-coordinates-td3214274.html
In similar notation as the example from David, try:

```
#... insert code to generate planeCut
planeCut.Update()    
for i in xrange(planeCut.GetOutput().GetNumberOfPoints()):
  p=[0,0,0]
  planeCut.GetOutput().GetPoint(i, p)
  print p[0],p[1],p[2]
```

You could also pass the data to numpy, on the vtk users, there is this example:
http://vtk.1045678.n5.nabble.com/Extract-Data-from-vtkImageReslice-to-numpy-array-td1246899.html#a1246902. In the same notation as the example from Eric, you could try:

```
import vtk.util.numpy_support as VN
#... insert code to generate planceCut
planeCut.Update()
pointData=planeCut.GetOutput().GetPointData() 
intensityPointArray= VN.vtk_to_numpy(pointData.GetArray('Intensity')) 
cellData=planeCut.GetOutput().GetCellData() 
intensityCellArray= VN.vtk_to_numpy(pointData.GetArray('Intensity'))
```

There are plenty more examples on vtk users archive :)